# How to implement custom SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter?

Tags: spring, filter, spring-integration, sftp

I am newbee to Spring integration. i am trying to implement customer sftp filter to list the files in SFTP server. I am getting "The blank final field seen may not have been initialized" at the constructor.Can you please suggest me to get list of file names from sftp server.

I dont have any idea what went wrong in my code.

Thanks in Advance

java code

```
public class SFTPFileFilter extends SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter {






    public SFTPFileFilter(String pattern) {
        super(pattern);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SFTPFileFilter.class);

    private final Queue<File> seen;

    private final Set<File> seenSet = new HashSet<File>();

    private final Object monitor = new Object();

    public static int fileCount = 0;

    @Autowired
    private SourcePollingChannelAdapter sftpInbondAdapter;



     public List<File> filterFiles(File[] files)
    {
         List<File> accepted = new ArrayList<File>();
            for (File file : files) {
                System.out.println(file.getName());
                accepted.add(file);
            }
            return accepted;
    }


    public boolean accept(File file) {
        synchronized (this.monitor) {
            if (this.seenSet.contains(file)) {
                logger.info(file.getName()+" is already copied earlier");
                return false;
            }
            if (this.seen != null) {
                if (!this.seen.offer(file)) {
                    File removed = this.seen.poll();
                    this.seenSet.remove(removed);
                    this.seen.add(file);
                }
            }
            this.seenSet.add(file);
            return true;
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private final Queue<File> seen;
```

You are not initializing that field in a constructor.

You can't extend it like that; simply override the method like this...

```
 public List<File> filterFiles(File[] files) {
        for (File file : files) {
            System.out.println("received:" + file.getName());
        }
        List<File> filtered = super.filterFiles(files);
        for (File file : flteredFiles) {
            System.out.println("after filter:" + file.getName());
        }
        return filteredFiles;
}
```